# Closing other elements when one element opens

Tags: angular

I am having a problem with figuring out the logic for my side-menu. I have a cascading menu and I need to make that when one cascading menu is open and i open another one, first one closes. The logic behind all this for opening menu is this. I am only toggling elements and that works fine.

```
if (this.router.url.indexOf('booking') > 0) {
  this.bookingOptions = true;
} else if (this.router.url.indexOf('settings') > 0) {
  this.accountOptions = true;
} else if (this.router.url.indexOf('reports') > 0) {
  this.reports = true;
} else if (this.router.url.indexOf('pricing') > 0) {
  this.pricingOptions = true;
} else if (this.router.url.indexOf('property') > 0) {
  this.propertyOptions = true;
}
```

I know the logic that I need to make other goes false when one is true, but every attempt was unsuccessful .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use CSS ?

Anyway, you asked, I provide. Since you want only one menu opened, then you should use only one variable.

I assume your URL is ending with the desired menu to open, if not, feel free to change it, or provide some URL examples so that I can change my answer :

```
const menuToOpen = this.router.url.split('/').pop();
```

In your HTML, use a condition to show them (again, provide your HTML if you want a custom answer)

```
<div class="menu" *ngIf="menuToOpen === 'settings'"></div>
```

Comment: Well replace `div` with `ul` then !

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: What do you mean ?